# ant & "no lwjgl in java.library.path"

Tags: java, ant, lwjgl

Within eclipse I try to get an ant task running which looks like this:

```
<target name="run-win-64" depends="jar-win-64">
    <java jar="${deploy.dir}/eco.jar" fork="true" dir="${deploy.dir}" >
        <arg value="-Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/natives" />
    </java>
</target>
```

and I get the titled error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in `java.library.path`

if I start my small program within my windows console (in the deploy directory) with following line:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/natives -jar eco.jar
```

everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<jvmarg>` instead of `<arg>`.